# How to remove "array" in front of np.array when i put it into a dictionary value with python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have to create a dictionary that has as key and Identifier and as value a random array generated with numpy, I would like to ask how I Can remove the "array" in front of the value when I put it as value into a dictionary...
I show an example where 3 is the key and the following array should be the value.

```
3: array([[10,  4,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [ 0, 10, 10,  0,  0,  0],
   [ 0,  0, 10, 10,  0,  0],
   [10,  0,  0, 10,  0,  0],
   [10,  0,  0,  0, 10,  0],
```

Comment: That word is part of the `repr` display of a numpy array.  The `str` display omits it and the commas.  Do you want an array or a list?

Comment: Please clarify what you want to do. ``array(...)`` is the *representation* of the value, it is not the actual value. There isn't a literal string ``array`` in front of the values – it merely shows that the type containing the values is a ``numpy.array``. You cannot remove the ``array(...)`` without changing the value to another type – do you actually want to do that, and if so which type do you desire?

Comment: Want to pass from an array to a list of list

Comment: Please show a clear example of what result your are expecting, and show your code   about your trial to solve this problem,
See MRE here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `alist=arr.tolist()` turns an array into python list (of lists)

Comment: Thank you @hpaulj this worked, have a nice evening

Answer (score 1):

You can just do something basic like this

```
list(array)
```

that will return the array as a list and get rid of the array word before.